# Spring Boot integration test for validating nested configuration properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

Using Spring Boot 2.6 I stumble across the following problem.

I defined a `ConfigurationProperties` class which maps the properties from `application.yml`. The configuration also includes validation annotations.

A missing property like `my.prefix.sample.username` prevents the applications from being started which is fine.

In a basic integration test however, this does not work. I would expect the below test to fail if `my.prefix.sample.password` was missing in `src/test/resources/application-integration-test.yml`. But it passes, so it seems as if the validation does really not kick in. If however I remove `my.prefix.sample.url`, then the test fails.

```java
// integration test
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public class ApplicationIT {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}

// the ConfigurationProperties classes

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @NotBlank
    @URL
    private String url;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    @Valid
    private SampleConfiguration sample;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class SampleConfiguration {

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: Is the `my.prefix.sample.password` defined in the default application properties file `application.properties`? If so, you will inherit this value. You can easily check the current value by injecting the `ApplicationConfiguration` to your integration test and printing the password to the console.

Comment: @rieckpil You are right. I also just found out that the values are "merged" from both the existing `src/main/resources/application.yml` and `src/test/resources/application-integration-test.yml`. Do you know if it is possible to ignore the "production" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're inheriting any property from your default application profile (`application.properties` inside `src/main/resources`), you can place an empty `application.properties` file inside `src/test/resources` to avoid inheriting any value.